# How to combine (merge) an array of identical DataFrames into a single one?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

How do I merge or combine an array of `DataFrames` in pandas?

```
dfs = []
for df in pd.read_csv(....chunksize=chunk_size):
  df1 = df
  # ....
  if condition:
    dfs.append(df1)
```

As you can see, they all have the same structure, I just need to combine them in a single `DataFrame`.

Comment: did you try 'result = concat(dfs)' at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

normally you can concatenate your array of data frame so you could have

```
import pandas as pd

dfs = []
for df in pd.read_csv(....chunksize=chunk_size):
  df1 = df
  # ....
  if condition:
    dfs.append(df1)
result = pd.concat(dfs)
```

you can find more info on this , [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).

Comment: This is the preferred method as periodically growing a df by repeatedly appending is non-performant

Comment: NameError: name 'concat' is not defined

Comment: For gods sake, add the import statement `from pandas import concat` in your answer. If you have already imported pandas `import pandas as pd`, you can use `pd.concat()`

Answer (score -1):

Pandas DataFrame already has an `append` method to merge two DataFrames
[See the documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html)

```
import pandas
dfs = pandas.DataFrame()
for df in pd.read_csv(....chunksize=chunk_size):
  df1 = df
  # ....
  if condition:
    dfs.append(df1)
```